# Installing Steam on Raspbian Solution Problem

Tags: pi-4, games

I'm trying to install Steam on Raspbian, and there is a [solution on Tom's Hardware I was following](https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/raspberry-pi-install-steam).  Problem I had was at the command

`sudo tar xvf data.tar.xz -C /`

It overwrote everything in my /usr/bin directory, which of course breaks the whole thing :)) (since there's no ls, sudo, etc.).  I'm wondering what way to get around this would be.

I have the 32 bit OS (as required for this hack), on a Pi 4 8GB.

Comment: `tar x` doesn't **remove** anything - so, I'm not sure I understand what you think is the problem

Comment: Sorry, but do you expect that we follow third party tutorials and explain and fix them?

Comment: @JaromandaX From `tar --help`: `tar -xf archive.tar  # Extract all files from archive.tar.` This will overwrite existing files and may make an operating system unusable if extracting to the root.

Comment: @Ingo - ***may** make* - depends what's IN the archive

Answer (score 1):

The tar file contains the following files

```
./etc/apt/sources.list.d/steam.list
./etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/steam.gpg
./usr/share/pixmaps/steam.png
./usr/share/pixmaps/steam_tray_mono.png
./usr/share/doc/steam/steam_subscriber_agreement.txt.gz
./usr/share/doc/steam/README
./usr/share/doc/steam-launcher/changelog.all.gz
./usr/share/doc/steam-launcher/copyright
./usr/share/applications/steam.desktop
./usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/steam.png
./usr/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps/steam.png
./usr/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/apps/steam.png
./usr/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps/steam.png
./usr/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/apps/steam.png
./usr/share/man/man6/steam.6.gz
./usr/lib/steam/bootstraplinux_ubuntu12_32.tar.xz
./usr/lib/steam/bin_steamdeps.py
./usr/lib/steam/steam.desktop
./usr/lib/steam/bin_steam.sh
./usr/bin/steam
./usr/bin/steamdeps
./lib/udev/rules.d/60-steam-input.rules
./lib/udev/rules.d/60-steam-vr.rules
```

As none of these files overwrite anything already existing in a standard install, it's a safe operation

**I've tried it and it does not remove anything from `/usr/bin`**

Comment: But ... the answer doesn't help to get a solution for the problem?

Comment: the problem is one of perception ... I've shown what's in the tar file and that executing `sudo tar xvf data.tar.xz -C /` **WONT** cause a problem

Comment: @Jaromanda X Yes I got the same result - I took a look as well and everything is still there, but when I was booted in (after running that command), nothing worked.  And when I tried to boot it, it couldn't boot.  What could this be?

Comment: At the time I thought they were removed since I couldn't ls, and said it couldn't find "ls" in /usr/bin, even though it was actually there (my instinct at the time was to assume it wasn't there, since bash(?) didn't find it when it looked, but clearly this is the wrong instinct)

Comment: but ... `ls` is in `/bin`

Comment: the boot issue may be the overclocking? `arm_freq=2147` I've never managed that high on any of my pi 4's - try without overclocking - it may run like a pig, but it'll determine if the overclock is the boot issue

Answer (score 0):

Try plugging your `sdcard` or any storage device to your `laptop/pc` and editting `/usr/bin` yourself. Configuring by yourself sometimes help me in that kind of problems.

Comment: `/usr/bin` is a directory and contains a lot of important and sensible system programs. What shall the OP edit there?